# How to work with FormArray and Angular-Material table

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular-Material and the component of mat-table, I'm trying to create a form to set some concepts to create a bill, but when I make the first push to the formArray this throws an error in the console, that says:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'partidaDetailLibre'

this is how I make the push to the form since component

```js
    datosFacturaLibre = this.formBuilder.group({
    
        concepts: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    
      })
    
      get newPartidaLibre(): FormGroup {
    
        return this.formBuilder.group({
    
          claveSat: [''],
          claveUnidadSat: [''],
          unidad: [''],
          quantity: [''],
          description: [''],
          totalCostFinalAmount: [''],
          totalCostFinalAmountWithCurrency: [''],
          subtotal: [''],
          subtotalWithCurrency: [''],
          totalIva: [''],
          totalIvaWithCurrency: [''],
          total: [''],
          totalWithCurrency: [''],
    
        })
    
      }
    
      get partidaDetailLibre(): FormArray {
    
        return this.datosFacturaLibre.get('concepts') as FormArray;
    
      }
    
      async addPartidaLibre() {
    
        await this.partidaDetailLibre.push(this.newPartidaLibre);
    
      }
```

And in the HTML I got as this

```html
    <form [formGroup]="datosFacturaLibre" autocomplete="off">
    
        <mat-card>
    
            <section style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="tipoFacturacion">
    
                <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
    
                    <mat-step label="Agregar conceptos">
                        <div formArrayName="partidaDetailLibre">
    
                            <div class="mat-elevation-z8" style="padding: 10px">
    
                                <table mat-table [dataSource]="partidaDetailLibre.controls">
    
                                    <!-- claveSat Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="number">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px"> # </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; index as i" [formGroup]="row"
                                            style="text-align: center; padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px">
                                            {{i+1}}
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- claveSat Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="claveSat">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Clave SAT
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; index as i" style="text-align: center"
                                            [formGroup]="row">
    
                                            <input type="text" matInput
                                                (keyup)="getClaveSat($event.target.value); filterClaveSat($event.target.value)"
                                                formControlName="claveSat" [matAutocomplete]="autoClaveSat" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;"/>
                                            <mat-autocomplete #autoClaveSat [panelWidth]="300">
                                                <mat-option (click)="changeClaveSat(claveSat, i)"
                                                    (onSelectionChange)="changeClaveSat(claveSat, i)"
                                                    *ngFor="let claveSat of filteredClaveSat" [value]="claveSat">
                                                    {{claveSat.c_claveprodserv}} - {{claveSat.descripcion}}
                                                </mat-option>
                                            </mat-autocomplete>
    
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- claveUnSat Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="claveUnSat">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Clave de
                                            unidad
                                        </th>
    
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; index as i" style="text-align: center"
                                            [formGroup]="row">
    
    
                                            <input type="text" matInput
                                                (keyup)="getClaveUnidadSat($event.target.value); filterClaveUnidadSat($event.target.value)"
                                                formControlName="claveUnidadSat" [matAutocomplete]="autoClaveUnidadSat"  style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;"/>
                                            <mat-autocomplete #autoClaveUnidadSat [panelWidth]="300">
                                                <mat-option (click)="changeClaveUnidadSat(claveUnidadSat, i)"
                                                    (onSelectionChange)="changeClaveUnidadSat(claveUnidadSat, i)"
                                                    *ngFor="let claveUnidadSat of filteredClaveUnidadSat"
                                                    [value]="claveUnidadSat">
                                                    {{claveUnidadSat.c_claveunidad}} - {{claveUnidadSat.nombre}}
                                                </mat-option>
                                            </mat-autocomplete>
    
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- unidad Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="unidad">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Unidad
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center" [formGroup]="row">
                                            <input matInput formControlName="unidad"
                                                style="height: 28px; text-align: center;" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- concepto Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="concepto">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Concepto
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center" [formGroup]="row">
                                            <input matInput formControlName="description"
                                                style="height: 28px; text-align: center;" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- cantidad Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="cantidad">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Cantidad
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center" [formGroup]="row">
                                            <input matInput formControlName="quantity"
                                                style="height: 28px; text-align: center;" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- precioUnitario Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="precioUnitario">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Precio
                                            Unitario
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center" [formGroup]="row">
                                            <input matInput formControlName="totalCostFinalAmountWithCurrency"
                                                style="height: 28px; text-align: center;" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- iva Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="iva">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> IVA </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center" [formGroup]="row">
                                            <input matInput formControlName="totalIvaWithCurrency"
                                                style="height: 28px; text-align: center;" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- total Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="total">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Total
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center" [formGroup]="row">
                                            <input matInput formControlName="totalWithCurrency"
                                                style="height: 28px; text-align: center;" style="border-bottom: 1px solid; width: 60px;">
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <!-- total Column -->
                                    <ng-container matColumnDef="acciones">
                                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center"> Acciones
                                        </th>
                                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="text-align: center"> acciones
                                        </td>
                                    </ng-container>
    
                                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsConceptsLibre"></tr>
                                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsConceptsLibre;"></tr>
    
                                </table>
    
                                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" style="margin-top: 16px">
    
                                    <table mat-table class="tbtotal" style="width: 40%;"
                                        [dataSource]="dataSourceConceptsTotals">
                                        <ng-container matColumnDef="concepto">
                                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Concepto</th>
                                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                                {{element.concept}}</td>
                                        </ng-container>
    
                                        <ng-container matColumnDef="monto">
                                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Monto</th>
                                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                                {{element.amount | currency}}</td>
                                        </ng-container>
    
                                        <ng-container matColumnDef="moneda">
                                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Moneda</th>
                                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                                {{element.currency}}</td>
                                        </ng-container>
    
                                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsConceptsTotalsLibre; sticky: true">
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsConceptsTotalsLibre;"></tr>
                                    </table>
    
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                    </mat-step>
                    <mat-step label="Timbrar">
                        <p>Segundo step</p>
                    </mat-step>
    
                </mat-horizontal-stepper>
    
            </section>
    
        </mat-card>
    
    </form>
```

I have a slide toggle to show or hide the form, when I make it appear,  in the stackblitz example it does not take much time, but on my pc it does

[stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-joaeag?file=src/app/app.component.html)

hope someone can help me to know how I can reduce the time taken to show the form and get rid of the console error

Answer (score 0):

The console error:

```
Error: Cannot find control with name: 'partidaDetailLibre'
```

It means that you haven't defined a FormArray with this name. In your code I can see:

```
datosFacturaLibre = this.formBuilder.group({
    concepts: this.formBuilder.array([]),
  });
```

and

```
 get partidaDetailLibre(): FormArray {
        return this.datosFacturaLibre.get('concepts') as FormArray;
    }
```

Change *concepts* with *partidaDetailLibre*. It solves the error.

On the other hand, why are you checking twice *tipoFacturacion*?

```
<form
  [formGroup]="datosFacturaLibre"
  autocomplete="off"
  *ngIf="tipoFacturacion"
>
  <mat-card>
    <section style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="tipoFacturacion">
      <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
        <mat-step label="Agregar conceptos">
          <div formArrayName="partidaDetailLibre">
......
```

It's not neccessary. Remove the second one.

If you want to show and hide the form, change the method of the  in this way:

```
cambioTipoFacturacion() {
        this.tipoFacturacion = !this.tipoFacturacion;
}
```

Here the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-91zmau?file=src/app/app.component.html) with your code and the changes:

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if we can use in strict mode `<input [formControl]="row.get('claveSat')"/>`  to avoid repeat the `[formGroup]="row"` in each td